# ROCA Implementation, Coppersmith Algorithm does not return roots

Tags: factoring, roca

We are currently trying to reproduce the implementation of the [ROCA-Paper](https://crocs.fi.muni.cz/_media/public/papers/nemec_roca_ccs17_preprint.pdf). Therefore we calculated $M'$ from $M$ and $Order_M'$ from $Order_M$ to reduce the search space, but when we hand these values to the coppersmith algorithm as described in Algorithm 1 of the paper, this algorithm does not find any roots.vIt only finds "potential" roots, which are fractional numbers and result in float numbers between $0$ and $1$.

These Roots have the form:

- 7903163834028830451137438186485015861/17304344567133368654502628603056098610,
- 213501605850162343745788742125935233/17304344567133368654502628603056098610, ...

Our Implementation can be found on [Github](https://github.com/r4ph4e1/ROCA_SAS.)

Does anybody have an idea, why the coppersmith algorithm does not return correct roots?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the function coppersmith_howgrave_univariate, you have

```
if gcd(modulus, result) >= modulus ^ beta:
```

You created $f$ as
$$
f(x) = x + (M'^{-1} \bmod N)(65537^{a'}\bmod M),
$$
so when you put $\mathrm{result} = f(\mathrm{root[0]})$, you do not get $p$ or a multiple of $p$, so the gcd makes no sense (and if ever you get a gcd greater than 1, you may have a factor of $N$).

I suggest that if root[0] is an integer, put it in roots and return that. That's what I did and it works fine.